# Output from one stage is not available for a subsequent one

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I have these two stages

```
stages:
- stage: PrepareBuildTools
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
       restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
 - stage: Build
   jobs:
   - job:
     steps:
     - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
       displayName: 'Initialize EntityFrameworkCore'
       inputs:
       command: custom
       custom: tool
       arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef'
     - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
       displayName: 'Create migration'
       inputs:
         command: custom
         custom: ef
         arguments: 'migrations script -i -o $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\migration.sql --project $(dbProject) -s $(startUpProject)'
     - task: VSBuild@1
       displayName: Build solution
       inputs:
         solution: '$(solution)'
         msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
         platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
         configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
     - task: FileTransform@1
       displayName: Transform appSettings.json
       inputs:
        folderPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip'
        fileType: 'json'
        targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

As you can see, the `Build solution` task builds the solution and produces `WebApp.zip` in `D:\a\1\a\`

The problem in that in a subsequent stage, the ZIP file is non existant, which leads me to believe the stages are all running in their own environment (different virtual machines?).

Is there any way to make sure every stage runs in the same environment ? I don't really need them to run in different ones, I mostly want to use stages so I can put an approval before an eventual "deploy" stage.

I tried defining a pool at the root of my YAML definition file as such:

```
pool:
 vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

Then assumed all stages would run on that one, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a couple more tasks to make that work

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy build output
  inputs:
    contents: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy migration file
  inputs:
   contents: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\migration.sql'
   targetFolder: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
   PathtoPublish: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
   ArtifactName: 'buildoutput'
   publishLocation: 'Container'
```

And in the stage where I need the files above, simply download the artifact

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
   artifactName: 'buildoutput'
   buildType: 'current'
   downloadType: 'single'
   downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

I can then use them as such: `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\buildoutput\WebApp.zip`